# How to debug my Test Classes?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, junit

I am working on integration test with JUnit. I have a some services ( Spring Services @Service) to test. So i create a test class to test services.

I have :
MyTestClass => ServicesToTest

When i execute my test, i cannot set a breakpoint and see what's happening in service classe. I know that when using Spring Service, Spring create some proxy to provide access to service. I don't know really if it is related to Spring.
How i can debug my Test class. For information my test classes is configured as below :

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:test-context.xml")
@Transactional
public class MyTestClass(){
     //Injection of dao and services + test method.
}
```

What's wrong, please ?

Comment: why `cannot set a breakpoint`?

Comment: When i set breakpoint, even at the begining of service method, breakpoint do not work. Execution does not stop

Comment: instead of RunAs, use DebugAs.  Also, breakpoints in java (eclipse) only work when they are on executable code, not on simple variable declarations.

Answer (score 0):

In case you are using Eclipse ensure that `Add line number attributes to generated class files` is checked. 
You will find this under **Window -> Preference -> Java -> Compiler** as shown below.

[image]